# How to change HTML menu li attributes vb

Tags: html, asp.net, html-lists, menuitem

I have a web page with master, two content pages and CSS , I would like to have the left side menu get class="current" when any of the pages appears

I tried every examples and all your answers like findcontrol and others but never work.

may be I have a problem cause I'm new to asp.net

regards

CSS sheet

```
#templatemo_left_content {
  float: left;
  background: #0a2035 url("/images/templatemo_left_bg.jpg") top no-repeat;
  width: 358px;
  display: inline;
}
```

/* Menu */

```
.templatemo_menu {
  float: right;
  width: 211px;
  margin: 20px 65px 35px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.templatemo_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 211px;
}

.templatemo_menu li a {
  display: block;
  height: 27px;
  padding: 7px 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: url("/images/templatemo_menu.gif") no-repeat; 
  text-decoration:none;
}

.templatemo_menu li a:hover, .templatemo_menu li .current {
  background: url(images/templatemo_menu_current.gif) no-repeat;    
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #00FFFF;
}
```

/* End of Menu */

master page html

```
<div id="templatemo_left_content">
  <div class="templatemo_menu">
    <ul  style="height: 265px">
      <li id="Home" runat="server"  ><a href="Default.aspx" >Home</a></li> 
      <li id="Products" runat="server" ><a href="#"  >Products</a></li>
      <li id="Services" runat="server" ><a href="#" >Services</a></li>  
      <li id="About" runat="server" ><a href="About.aspx"  >About</a></li>
      <li id="Company" runat="server"><a href="#">About Our Company</a></li>
      <li id="Contact" runat="server" ><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li id="Customers" runat="server"><a href="#l">Our Customers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, asked a question and discover the answer by yourself
that is what happens

for you all thanks for reading and being involved

when you use it this way of creating Li

```
<li id="Home" runat="server"  ><a href="Default.aspx" >Home</a></li>
```

and uses the following code

Dim li As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

```
     li = Page.Master.FindControl("Home")
     li.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
```

vb is calling home and it will change the the class but for a reason the menu background doesn't change cause it is located in tag a and not in tag Li
so playing a little with the master html to adjust and place the id="Menu_Home" (can not use Home as the text has the same that is why I name it Menu_Home) inside tag a not in Li, also runat="server" will be shifted to to tag a as well
it will be as following:

```
                    <div class="templatemo_menu">
                    <ul style="height: 235px">
                        <li><a href="Home.aspx" id="Menu_Home" runat="server"  >Home</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#" id="Menu_Products" runat="server" >Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="Menu_Services" runat="server" >Services</a></li>    
                        <li ><a href="#" id="Menu_Customers" runat="server">About Our Company</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About.aspx" id="Menu_About" runat="server"  >About</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#" id="Menu_Contact" runat="server">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and in master load event add this code:

```
        Dim thisURL As String = Me.Page.[GetType]().Name.ToString()
    Select Case thisURL
        Case "home_aspx"
            Menu_Home.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
            Exit Select
        Case "about_aspx"
            Menu_About.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
            Exit Select
        Case "logout_aspx"
            Menu_Products.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
            Exit Select
    End Select
```

every thing is going to be fine

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the control in your master or on your current page?

Try adding this to Page_Load in Default.aspx:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("Home");
li.Attributes.Add("class", "current");
```

Comment: control in master page

Comment: the problem is that
we can find the control but when execute the following code in every  page_load, nothing changes

        'Dim li As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

        'li = Page.Master.FindControl("Home")

        'li.Attributes.Add("class", "current")

Comment: Finally I discovered the reason
I'll posted as answer so others can get benefit too

thanks Magnus